# Get website URL for XML file JSP-Java

Tags: java, html, xml, file, jsp

Let's say i have created the file

```
String path = application.getRealPath("userSearchFolder");
String name = path + "/" + (String) session.getAttribute("username") + ".xml";
File file = new File(name);
```

And later I want to make it available as a link, for example

```
 <a href"<%=file.toURI()%>">File</a>
```

What happens is I get the directory path not url path ->

```
file:/D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/2012/GATE_Project/build/web/userSearchFolder/mjoraid.txt.xml
```

And when it reaches Firefox, I hover over the link and what i see is

```
file:///D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/2012/GATE_Project/build/web/userSearchFolder/mjoraid.xml
```

When I right click and choose Copy link Location and paste it in URL the xml file opens, but when I click the link, nothing happens.

How could I get a link like this

```
http://localhost:8080/GATE_Project/somepage/somepage/mjoraid.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did it manually, similar to how i used to do it in php, create a variable that contains the website main directory.

```
  String searchFolderURL = "http://localhost:8080/GATE_Project/userSearchFolder/";
```

and then

```
 <a href="<%=searchFolderURL + file.getName()%>" target="_blank"  >See original txt File </a>
```

Thanks btw.

Answer (score 1):

The `getRealPath` will give a **File** system path (hence "real"), as opposed to web app path. So you cannot make it a href.

The following should suffice.

```
<a href="/userSearchFolder/${userName}.xml">
```

*(Of course you are risking data mining for such public accessible XML files.)*

Answer (score 0):

You could use a servlet to serve the file.

This [tutorial](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-serve-up-a-pdf-from-a-servlet.html) shows how to serve a pdf file(!)

the theory is the same:

- you load the file in the servlet
- Set any required headers
- write the data to the response

The ContentType should probably be "application/xml".